# Print negated words that follows "no,not,never" in a sentence in Python

Tags: python, nltk, negation

How do I print all negated word that follows "no","not", "never" so on. The sentence is

```
SENTENCE="It was never going to work.I'm not happy"
```

Desired output

```
going,happy (Which follows never and not)
```

Any help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please keep in mind that this is not a "code this for me" website.  Please show us what you already did and tell us where your problems lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need `ntlk` for that. I'd split the string (using regex to split according to non-alphanums (or you have an issue with `work.I'm` part), and build a list comprehension which looks for the previous word belonging to the "negative" words.

```
import re

SENTENCE="It was never going to work.I'm not happy"

all_words = re.split("\W+",SENTENCE)

words = [w for i,w in enumerate(all_words) if i and (all_words[i-1] in ["not","never","no"])]

print(words)
```

result:

```
['going', 'happy']
```

Comment: Thank you. Its a great Solution